# Store large amount of data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, string

Im receiving some file chunks in bytes format from my server and im collecting them into one variable in my frontend to download it later. And I can't change my server conception (receiving a file sliced into chunks).

My problem is that if the file is heavy (from 500MB), my variable length is starting to be very very big and im having an error :

```
RangeError: Invalid string length
```

This is because my variable has reach the limit of character (536 800 000).

Here's how im adding my data to my variable :

```
this.socket.on('new_file', (data: string) => {
  this.receivedFile += data;
}
```

My download part :

```
public download(): void {
    const byteCharacters = this.receivedFile;
    const byteArrays = [];
    const sliceSize=512

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 
     sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: this.fileInfos.type});

    saveAs(blob, this.fileInfos.name);
  }
```

Which approach can I do ? Or does it exist some variable type in Javascript to accept more char ? Thanks

Comment: How big are we talking about? And why would you need to store this in a string? For what do you even need the file chunks on the frontend?

Comment: "*I can't change this structure.*" - then what *can* you change? It might help if you would post your code. It's not really clear what "*adding some file chunks from my server into one variable*" exactly means.

Comment: Hi @Bergi I've updated my post, hope Im more clear now.

Comment: Ok, but what is `data`? Where does it come from, what is its type, why do you need to call `.toString()`?

Comment: "*to download it later*" - how are you going to do that? You probably want to construct a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead of a string.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, for the variable data informations i've updated tu full code.

Comment: Yes for the download part I have made this function in the post, but Im not sure this is the best way

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's much better to work with. I assume `this.receivedFile` is initialised to an empty string when the connection (or download) is opened? What is `url2 = url.split(',')[1]` doing, does the server somehow send comma-delimited data?

Comment: Ah it's changing :-)

Comment: My bad.. I've copied the wrong one. This time is ok ^^'

Comment: Does the server send base64-encoded data? Is each chunk base64-encoded on its own, or do you need to decode the entire thing in the end?

Comment: The server is sending me binaryString at every chunk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't collect the chunks into a huge string. Instead, just convert each chunk into a bytearray immediately (that you'll need later anyway) and collect these:

```
this.socket.on('new_file', (data: string) => {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  this.byteArrays.push(bytes);
}
```

then

```
public download(): void {
  const blob = new Blob(this.byteArrays, {type: this.fileInfos.type});
  saveAs(blob, this.fileInfos.name);
}
```

I don't think you need to make 512-byte-sized slices.

Comment: Thank you!! This saved my night.. It was my download part where I was wrong.